# How do I say ' my cellphone is about to die' in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I say ' my cellphone is about to die' in Spanish?

> Celular acaba de morir.

Is acaba de the right expression? And is "die" translated literally or idiomatically in this context?

Comment: In cuba we also say `mi celular se fue del parque/ o pasó a mejor vida`...pero creo que solo lo entenderan en cuba

Comment: @EmilioGort aunque no entendería *se fue del parque* sin más contexto, que el móvil *pasó a mejor vida* creo que se entendería en casi todo lugar.

Comment: I'm sorry to bring this up about such an old question, but for translation requests, we really want to focus on specific doubts, rather than providing long lists of possible translations. What specific doubt or question do you have about your proposed translation?

Comment: @guifa aunque no se el origen de `se fue del parque`, se entiende en Cuba como que algo dejo de funcionar o murió, me imagino debe referirse a lo que pasaba con las municiones cuando los soldados se quedaban sin parque. digo yo adivinando

Comment: @Flimzy: I broke down the question and wonder if it can be reopened in its current form.

Comment: @TomAu: Yes, that's better (although "acaba" is a verb, not a preposition :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para completar las respuestas anteriores, en España se dice

> mi móvil no tiene batería

o

> a mi móvil se le está acabando la batería

Comment: The translation shouldn't have the word "bateria" because the original expression in English doesn't have the word.

Comment: It does not matter if it has the word in it: you are not saying that your mobile phone is not working correctly and "is about to die" or broken. You mean it has no battery, so that's the way you say it in spanish. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Here in Chile is very common "Mi celular está muriendo" meaning that your cell phone is running out of battery. I know it is absolutely informal but widespread.

Comment: That is a common expresion in Perú too.

Comment: ¡Que zora, Caleta grax!

Comment: Same in Mexico.

Answer (score 3):

> Se le acaba la pila al móvil. // Se acaba la pila de mi móvil.

o bien

> La batería del celular se está acabando.
>
> A mi celular/móvil le queda (muy) poca batería.

I would use neither *mi celular acaba de morir* nor *mi celular se está muriendo*, although some people do.

Comment: En mi pais nosotros decimos bateria, decimos pila solamente cuando nos referimos a las AA o AAA

Comment: @EmilioGort También en Colombia.

Comment: @Mauricio estuve 1 año viviendo por Colombia, en Buga y Barranquilla, conozco un poco de tu maravillosa tierra

Answer (score 2):

In Spain: Mi móvil está a punto de morir.

Varias respuestas dan por hecho que se está quedando sin batería, cuando la pregunta original no lo indica.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct translation would be:

> Se me está por morir el celular/cel/teléfono

At least here in Uruguay we use that expression a lot and means the same.
(You can use any of the 3 words I used to refer to the cellphone, depending the region, in Uruguay we use mostly these 3 but in Spain the use a lot *móvil* or another could be *teléfono móvil* but I don't know if that's used in some place).

And I think you shouldn't take translatations that uses the *batería* word specifically because depending the context, the same phrase could mean that the cellphone isn't working properly or it's very damaged or something.

BTW,

> acaba de morir

is wrong because you say that when you cellphone just died, and not when it's about to.

Comment: ¡Ta. Gracias, tío!

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de Alberto es completamente correcta, no obstante también se te entiende, y son usadas las expresiones que te pongo a continuación y creo que son una traducción más literal de lo que enuncias arriba.

> Mi móvil va a morir.
>
> Mi móvil está a punto de morir.

Answer (score 1):

in Venezuela we say

> mi celular esta apunto de morirse

o

> mi celular se va a morir

Answer (score -2):

It's easy.

> Mi cel casi no tiene pila.

The last three words mean *to die* in the sentence.